# Fortran 90: allocatable array cannot appear in "EQUIVALENCE"

Tags: fortran90

I have a large array, the array is so large that I have to use "allocatable" and allocate in fortran. for example,

```
complex(8),allocatalbe :: E0(:, :, :)
allocate(E0(1000,1000,1000))
```

I need in our code to transform the array's form from `E0(1000,1000,1000)` to `E1(1000*1000,1000)`, i.e., transform a three-dimension array `E0(M,N,L`) to its corresponding two-dimension `E1(M*N,L)`.
However, I cannot use the statements: `Equivalence (E0,E1)` due to its 'allocatable'.
I don't like to define or allocate another array such as `E1(M*N,L)` due to limited memory.

Have anyone have some method to achieve: `Equivalence(E0,E1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the rank three array to a specific procedure that has an explicit shape or assumed size dummy argument of rank two.  Sequence association between the actual argument and the dummy argument will give you the equivalent of equivalence.

```
PROGRAM remap
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:,:)
  INTEGER :: i
  !****
  ALLOCATE(a(2,3,4))
  a = RESHAPE( (/ (REAL(i), i=1, PRODUCT(SHAPE(a))) /), SHAPE(a))
  CALL remapped(a, SIZE(a,1) * SIZE(a,2), SIZE(a,3))
CONTAINS  
  SUBROUTINE remapped(b,n,m)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n, m
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: b(n,m)
    !****
    ! Should print the first "page" of the actual argument.
    PRINT "(99(F6.1,:,' '))", b(:,1)
  END SUBROUTINE remapped
END PROGRAM remap
```

Later standards have the additional option of pointer rank remapping.

Comment: Thank you! you employ the intrinsic function RESHAPE. There seems a little compicated, especially, it need allocate dynamically two array: E(M,N,L) and E(M*N,L).
 integer(4), allocatable,dimension(:,:,:) :: E01
      integer(4), allocatable,dimension(:,:) :: E02
    allocate(E01(M,N,L)) 
    allocate(E02(M*N,L))
    ! define E01(M,N,L)   
    E02=reshape(E01,(/M*N,L/))
  However, I hope E01 and E02 share the same memory. i.e. Equivalence (E01,E02). they are completely the same thing in computer's memory. Do you have another method?

Comment: The reshape intrinsic is only used in the example code to define (give a value to) the example array ``a``.  It is not used to change the shape of that array.  You can change that ``a = ...`` statement to any other statement(s) of your choosing to define ``a`` (e.g. ``a = 0``, if you wanted).  The array with the different rank is the ``b`` dummy argument of the ``remapped`` procedure.  The actual argument `a`` has rank three, the dummy argument ``b`` has rank two.  The storage for both arguments will be the same on most Fortran processors.